# Best way to order operations to remove SQL partitioning from existing table

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have existing Azure SQL databases where the largest table has partitioning enabled, splitting on months. Having read up on this feature e.g. [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-decide-if-should-use-table-partitioning/) and [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/database-administration-sql-server/gail-shaws-sql-server-howlers/) I suspect this was not a good choice and is probably hurting our performance if anything. Our volumes are not high enough, hardly any queries filter on the partition key, nothing about our loading process is designed with partitioning in mind, etc.

I've written a script that removes it, for which I have to:

- drop all indexes (including the clustered index)
- create a proper PK clustered index on `PRIMARY`
- `DROP PARTITION SCHEME`
- `DROP PARTITION FUNCTION`
- recreate all the other indexes

There typically aren't a huge number of rows in the table (a few million at most) but in a test run (on 400 eDTUs) it just took two hours.

Is there a "best" order to drop the indexes in to minimise the amount of work?

Comment: The only things that take time is dropping clustered index, creating clustered index and creating NC-indexes, dropping NC indexes is done in the background. It might be faster (and have less downtime) to create a new table with correct PK, copy the data there in batches and then create NC indexes and finally rename the tables

Comment: If you have a Partitioned clustered index then you can simply execute CREATE INDEX command with option Drop existing = on and create the index on your primary file group.

Comment: I agree, probably better to just recreate the whole table, copy the data over, and do a `sp_rename` switcheroo. You would need to drop and recreate the foreign keys also if any

Comment: But probably best to migrate this to [dba.se]

Comment: @M.Ali if that works without requiring dropping/creating all other indexes then that's well worth knowing!

Answer (score 1):

My Understanding is dropping indexes, First drop non-clustered indexes and then the clustered index Later  the partition scheme and partition function.

Afterwards recreating the indexes, First create the clustered index afterwards partition scheme and partition function, and later the non-clustered indexes.

In this way minimize the amount of work required to recreate the indexes.

For Example I Have created a table that demonstartes for the Dropping and Deletion of the Indexes and Partitions.

```
CREATE  TABLE tablet_info (

ID INT  IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY  KEY,

Name  VARCHAR(50),

CreatedDate DATE

)

  

INSERT  INTO tablet_info (Name, CreatedDate)

VALUES

('John', '2023-01-01'),

('Jane', '2023-02-01'),

('Mark', '2023-03-01'),

('Sarah', '2023-04-01')
```

[image]

I have created the below.
[image]

As you said you have a large table. and for large tables you can follow below sequence. this order will help  you minimize the amount of data movement
**1>Drop the non-clustered index**

```
DROP  INDEX INDEX_tablet_info_Name ON tablet_info
```

**2>Drop the clustered index**

```
DROP  INDEX PK_tablet_info_ID ON tablet_info
```

**3>Drop the partition scheme and function**

```
ALTER  TABLE tablet_info DROP  CONSTRAINT PK_tablet_info_ID

DROP  PARTITION  SCHEME PartSchem_tablet_info_Month

DROP  PARTITION  FUNCTION PartFunc_tablet_info_Month
```

**Recreate the primary key constraint**

ALTER  TABLE tablet_info ADD  CONSTRAINT PK_tablet_info_ID PRIMARY  KEY  CLUSTERED (ID)

**Recreate the clustered index**

```
CREATE  CLUSTERED  INDEX PK_tablet_info_ID ON tablet_info (ID)
```

**Recreate the non-clustered index**

```
CREATE  INDEX IX_tablet_info_Name ON tablet_info (Name)
```

Comment: This makes sense. I guess if I were to drop the clustered index first then SQL would have to rewrite all my non-clustered indexes so they refer to the DB-generated internal row ID, which would all be wasted effort.